# Add double quote to the first element

Tags: javascript

My timestamp have not the double quote and I need the double quote to the first element (all timestamp)

I tried to use replace but error say : chaine.replace is not a function

```
    var globalTab = [];
    globalTab.push(TabJSON)
    console.log(globalTab)
    // OUTPUT 
    [[{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:26:00.000Z, Average: 200},
        {Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:32:00.000Z, Average: 200},
        {Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:26:00.000Z, Average: 200},
        {Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:29:00.000Z, Average: 200},
        {Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:35:00.000Z, Average: 200}],
    [{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:26:00.000Z, Average: 200},
        {Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:32:00.000Z, Average: 200},
        {Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:26:00.000Z, Average: 200},
        {Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:29:00.000Z, Average: 200},
        {Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:35:00.000Z, Average: 200}]]

chaine = globalTab
chaine=chaine.replace(/(\d{4}-\d{2}[^,]+,)/g,'"$1"');
console.log(chaine)
// Error
```

Expected result :

```
  [[{Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:26:00.000Z", Average: 200},
        {Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:32:00.000Z", Average: 200},
        {Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:26:00.000Z", Average: 200},
        {Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:29:00.000Z", Average: 200},
        {Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:35:00.000Z", Average: 200}],
    [{Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:26:00.000Z", Average: 200},
        {Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:32:00.000Z", Average: 200},
        {Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:26:00.000Z", Average: 200},
        {Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:29:00.000Z", Average: 200},
        {Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:35:00.000Z", Average: 200}]]
```

Comment: Where is `globalTab`defined ?

Comment: Yeah sorry, i display only the most important part of my script. It's defined before

Comment: That's just  the consoles output of a date object. Why exactly do you want to add `""`? Because it doesn't make sense to do this to an object. I'm presuming you want to produce json?

Comment: You can stringify your whole json object instead.

Comment: @SudhirOjha there is no such thing as a JSON object...JSON is a string

Comment: So it's not possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to convert this to a string... so, in my console i did this for test:

```
var globalTab = `[[{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:26:00.000Z, Average: 200},
    {Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:32:00.000Z, Average: 200},
    {Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:26:00.000Z, Average: 200},
    {Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:29:00.000Z, Average: 200},
    {Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:35:00.000Z, Average: 200}],
[{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:26:00.000Z, Average: 200},
    {Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:32:00.000Z, Average: 200},
    {Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:26:00.000Z, Average: 200},
    {Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:29:00.000Z, Average: 200},
    {Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:35:00.000Z, Average: 200}]]`
```

After that, modify your replace to this:

```
globalTab = globalTab.replace(/(\d{4}-\d{2}[^,]+Z)/g,'"$1"');
```

And the result you expected (you can test in your browser console):

```
"[[{Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:26:00.000Z", Average: 200},
    {Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:32:00.000Z", Average: 200},
    {Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:26:00.000Z", Average: 200},
    {Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:29:00.000Z", Average: 200},
    {Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:35:00.000Z", Average: 200}],
[{Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:26:00.000Z", Average: 200},
    {Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:32:00.000Z", Average: 200},
    {Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:26:00.000Z", Average: 200},
    {Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:29:00.000Z", Average: 200},
    {Timestamp: "2019-01-15T08:35:00.000Z", Average: 200}]]"
```

Hope it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it is the most efficent way, but i try in this way cuz also i dont know if it is sa string, or array of arrays. You are using replace like if it was an string but it seem like an array, even when you dont see the quotes, implicitly they are there if it is an object. Anyway. With this i think it will work for you.

```
    var newGlobalTab=[];
    for (var i=0;i<globalTab.length;i++){
        var elem=[]
        for (var j in globalTab[i]){
            elem.push({Timestamp:'"'+globalTab[i][j]["Timestamp"]+'"', Average:globalTab[i][j]["Average"]});
        }
        newGlobalTab.push(elem);
    }
    console.log(newGlobalTab);
```

I hope it can be helful for you, and sorry that i cannot bring the most efficient way. Also sorry for my English, i use to speak spanish.